# Uninstall/Remove Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uninstall

I was changing the case and PSU of my kid's desktop computer. It was 2015 HP Desktop - Intel Quad core computer. Lots of parts and upgrades being done on it and latest one was GPU(Nvidia 1005 Ti)-so it was due for a change of PSU and case(for better airflow). It has 5 SATA port on - as the [new case](https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16811129268?Item=N82E16811129268) is not having the 5.25" bay - so DVD drive cannot be used. It had two SSD and one 3.5inch hard drive. I didn't took a picture of how the SSDs and hard drives were connected on this [motherboard](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03748942).
Everything is done within few hours but we are getting this error POST BIOS:
No boot disk has been detected or the disk has been failed. Tried various combinations to connect the hard drive and SSDs on the motherboard - error not going away. I took out the SSD and found that SSD(500 GB) has Windows, SSD(1TB)- Windows D drive or data only while the 3.5 inch hard drive is Ubuntu Linux. I have no idea when we last time created dual boot - where GRUB or LILO was installed. My son didn't used Ubuntu at all so we can afford to uninstall/delete Ubuntu Linux and install it when needed.
I somehow logged into that computer and created Windows recovery media(on USB). Now how i can uninstall Ubuntu and GRUB/LILO so that it's pure Windows computer?

I will instal Ubuntu Linux on that computer, later when the kid develop some interest for Ubutnu linux.

Comment: If you boot into the bios/UEFI interface does it show the Windows disk? You might need to set which drive to boot in there. Alternatively try connecting it to one of the other SATA ports. They appear to be different colours which suggests different functions. Strangely there doesn’t seem to be a manual available. Try different SATA cables too, one might be faulty

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created Windows installation media following [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d) and installed Windows 10 all over again on the C drive(SSD- 500 GB). Everything is back to normal now. Ubuntu/Grub got overwritten using this way.